# java memory options

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-management

I am using Java version 1.6.0_21.

These are the memory options I have set:

```
export MEM_OPTS="-Xmx3072m -Xms3072m -XX:NewSize=1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

My server is having 10 GB RAM.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 32776 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?
>   Internal Error (allocation.cpp:215), pid=28197, tid=44
>   Error: Chunk::new
>   JRE version: 6.0_21-b06
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (17.0-b16 mixed mode solaris-sparc )

Any idea? Why this is coming as I have 10 GB memory on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check following post something similar problem

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 1958536 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435819/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-requested-1958536-bytes-for-chunknew-out-of-swap)

```
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,org/apache/velocity/runtime/directive/Foreach,render
```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=219023686

I think above command may help

Comment: If it's indeed [this bug](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do;jsessionid=b98315519dae341456a280ba6488a?bug_id=6916062) (as found following your link), then a simple update to Java 6u22 (or 6u23, never really grasped the precise terminology in the bug database) should solve the problem.

Comment: @KPBird : Thanks.Now i have updated my server with java 6u26.Now this solved.But now my application is not able to create any thread.Getting OutOfMemory."java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread"...my server is having 10 GB ram.Please let me know : How MaxNewSize,MaxPermSize segregate 10 GB memory.Why i am getting OutOfMemory ? Any Idea