# Jahia/JVM/Tomcat Crash

Tags: crash, jvm

we are using following configuration:

CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -Dcertain.config=/data02/certain/config -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -server -Dhibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=true -verbose:gc -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=512m -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+AggressiveHeap -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps"

JDK 1.6 version 22

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.  CPU:total 4 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core)  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.1-b03) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_22-b04)

we keep getting:

## # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

## # java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 17179869200 bytes for Chunk::new. Out of swap space?

# #  Internal Error (allocation.cpp:215), pid=5845, tid=139708177794816

## Error: Chunk::new

## # JRE version: 6.0_22-b04 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)

Comment: Seems this is already answered here : 

[Out of memory and chunk new out of space space][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435819/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-requested-1958536-bytes-for-chunknew-out-of-swap

Comment: Although I agree with Serge, what surprises me here is the amouth of memory requested. Jahia 'seems' to be requesting 16GB of memory and I have never seen Jahia doing that. I wonder if this is not some kinda bug beeing hit?